# Sublime Text - Fake whitespace sizing

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Let's say I wish to follow the conventions of a Framework or Community which defines that the application should use 2 spaces.

If I find it easier to read 4 spaces is there an existing method in sublime to make it appear as if 2 spaces are 4, but in reality it is still 2 spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you are looking for, but I can suggest two alternatives:

1) You could write your entire script using the 4 spaces that you prefer, and then once it is all done, convert it to a text file and parse through it line by line, writing every line to a new file as follows (in Python):

```
>>> x = "Hello    jshthornton,    here    is    an    example"
>>> print x.replace("    ", "  ")
Hello  jshthornton,  here  is  an  example
```

This new file that you create will hold all the same information as your original, except it will be in the correct format.

2) You could try editing the true-type font itself so that the spaces are double width; two spaces would take up the same amount of space as four. I have no personal experience editing fonts but in interest I took a look at [this](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-create-your-own-fonts-and-edit-truetype-fonts/), could potentially solve your problem.

Personally I would prefer method 1, it's a simple script & it will let you write your document in the format you prefer with (hardly) any extra work.

Comment: For me edit the font is a very good idea if the file needs to be shared by other persons (so it realy has to use 2 spaces); only problem I see is that this affect single spaces separating words and all other spaces, but is not a big problem. +1 for that one.